# flutter upgrade : The Flutter SDK is tracking a non-standard remote issue

Tags: flutter, dart, upgrade, flutter-upgrade

[image][image]Hello im trying to upgrade flutter sdk but im facing this issue when i type flutter upgrade
the pics are for the issue and the flutter doctor results

Comment: did you fork the flutter repo?

Comment: hmmm i just started with this programming world so im not familiar with these git thing how do i do that please?

Comment: I checked on your GitHub profile and you did

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clone the original flutter repository (instead of a fork as you did) to be able to upgrade. So delete your current sdk and clone it from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter)